# Force second handler to be executed, bind with on

Tags: jquery

I have written a template parser in JavaScript. It renders a 'project' into a calendar and appends a click handler. When you click the project container it starts loading the project content in an other window. So far so good. But at one point I need to overwrite this click handler and replace it with another one. Sounds easy at first, but my program uses a mix of push and polling services and the project has to been rendered several times a minute (it will be complete replaced, at least in the first iteration).

The normal click handler is added using jQuery's `click()` method. The special click handler is added using jQuery's `on()` method, since all projects have to be clickable with this new handler. Now, every time the project is re-rendered the click handler will be appended and executed before the handler added with `on` :(

I *could* set a flag at the templater so that he can decide which handler he should add to the project, but that would interfere with our program paradigms we were using where each module must be complete executable without interacting with other modules.

Any suggestions? Could I prioritize the handlers?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove previous click hander before binding new one.

```
$yourObject.off('click');
           .on('click', function(event){
               //do sth
            });
```

http://api.jquery.com/off/

If you have more then one click, and want to unbind only some of them use event namespacing.

Binding:

```
$yourObject.on('click.module-name');
```

Unbinind only click event handlers from namespace:

```
$yourObject.off('click.module-name');
```

Unbinding all event handlers from namespace:

```
 $yourObject.off('.module-name');
```